# Large space under my slick.js slider

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to implement a slider for a website that's meant to have deconstructed background images with super imposed text.  However, loading the text into the slider creates a big white space, which I'm looking to get rid of.  The HTML says its an issue in the .slick-track style.

here's a js fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/bwu778/7dyhgzgf/
css:

```
#container1{
  position: relative;
}

#image{
  position:absolute;
}

#text1{
  z-index:100;
  position:absolute;
  color:#4D2E82;
  left:22%;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:12%;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

#text2{
  z-index:99;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color:#4D2E82;
  left:25%;
  margin-top:20%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your fiddle into my localserver and got a white space as well. Upon further inspection, it seems there are numerous issues. To name a few things to check:

- make sure you install the slick-theme.css locally since your link
  reference is listed as such `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>`

  - The initializer function on their website is erroneous
  - The encoding messages are on their end, which they are probably aware
    of because utf-8 is sprinkled liberally in one document
  - use the actual jquery cdn files or add the `http` to the ones from
    their website in case you copied them directly

Not sure how imperative it is for you to continue with Slick but judging from the syntax and the 645 open issues, I recommend perusing the closed issues for some answers